# How can I print solana logs with rust?

Tags: solana-program, solana-test-validator

can anyone help me in this, i am trying to get Solana logs on vs code terminal but it is not showing.i tried with this command "solana logs --url localhost" but i did not get.may i know what is the reason for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For logs

You can pass the program address as an argument like this `solana logs [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] [ADDRESS]` which is

```
solana logs --url localhost PROGRAM_ADDRESS
```

For more details, you can refer to [this](https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-logs) page.

Comment: still it is not showing.i tried it already

Comment: @poojitha are you deploying to the local cluster?

Comment: yes i am deploying to the local cluster